# Visual C++ 2015 std::unordered_set performance

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unordered-set

I wrote a very simple program to benchmark the performance of `std::set<int>` vs `std::unordered_set<int>`. When I run this program on GCC, `unordered_set` is much faster. But if I run the same code on Visual C++ 2015, `set` clearly outperforms `unordered_set`.

Am I missing something obvious? I've searched around for anything that mentions performance problems with `unordered_set` on Visual C++ but I haven't found anything. Of course, I am running in Release mode with all the usual optimizations turned on.

Here are the results, the 1st column is proportional to the amount of times `insert` is called, `set` is the 2nd column and `unordered_set`is the 3rd. The timings are in microseconds, the lower the better.

```
// with GCC 4.9.2

1   23.208  11.323  
2   31.705  10.805  
3   41.113  11.671  
4   51.124  12.742  
5   60.941  13.931  
6   69.642  14.083  
7   75.245  15.151  
8   84.227  15.983  
9   93.464  17.415  
10  102.419 18.036  
11  121.212 19.979  
12  129.748 20.908  
13  140.378 22.201  
14  151.061 23.131  
15  151.483 23.289  
16  162.107 24.252  
17  170.408 24.746  
18  175.369 25.73   
19  184.257 26.835  
20  192.877 29.459  
21  214.805 30.461  
22  223.105 30.977  
23  221.382 31.037  
24  230.129 32.398

// with Visual C++ 2015

1   24.761  32.473
2   31.075  47.305
3   39.309  58.974
4   44.749  73.753
5   51.608  81.204
6   58.141  96.035
7   67.309  106.105
8   75.653  118.712
9   80.801  126.99
10  88.548  144.899
11  95.388  165.135
12  105.546 170.017
13  108.9   177.442
14  117.891 192.446
15  125.177 194.573
16  130.842 212.399
17  138.182 242.828
18  144.113 240.621
19  151.28  262.748
20  158.495 265.814
21  168.463 277.699
22  178.542 295.593
23  181.643 304.112
24  191.779 317.013
```

And here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <chrono>

template<typename T>
T InsertTest(const int count, const int repeat)
{
    T set;

    for (int k = 0; k < repeat; ++k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            set.insert(i * (repeat + 1));
        }
    }

    return set;
}

int main()
{
    for (int repeat = 1; repeat < 25; ++repeat)
    {
        std::cout << repeat << '\t';
        {
            const auto beg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            InsertTest<std::set<int>>(100000, repeat);
            const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - beg).count() / 1000.0f << '\t';
        }

        {
            const auto beg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            InsertTest<std::unordered_set<int>>(100000, repeat);
            const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - beg).count() / 1000.0f << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you start the program **without debugging** in release mode?

Comment: Yes I did, compiled in release, then run outside the IDE.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my machine (VS2015 Update 1, Release build, x86 and x64). For example, my last line is `24  163.479 79.866`

Comment: @Blastfurnace interesting! I am running VS2015 REL, I'll investigate this.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce, but consistently, with or without optimization with MSVC 2015 the hashed set is just *marginally* faster. While with g++ it's two to three times faster.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for trying it out, are you running REL or SP1?

Comment: VS says "D14REL", the compiler says "Version 19.00.23026 for x64". Oh I didn't notice. This was 64-bit.

Comment: Well it's the same with 32-bit MSVC, the unordered set is just marginally faster. Last line is "24      321.401 211.401", with `/O2` (this is an old laptop running Windows 7).

Comment: I tried on another computer also running VS2015REL, and I am also getting results where the set is 50% slower than the unordered_set. I copied the compiled executable from one compiler to another, and running the same binary on one computer set is consistently faster, on the other unordered_set is consistently faster. I am completely lost now.

Comment: Am I the only one questioning validity of your benchmark? Sorted insert is clearly biased against the set. Also, do you really intend to insert the same 100,000 elements `repeat` number of times? I thought that the plan was to increase the set size in each iteration. (Found this by adding set size to the output to avoid compiler optimization; each row has set size of 100,000).

Comment: @VladFeinstein thanks! there is indeed a mistake, my intent was to use (k+1) and not (repeat+1), but after the fix it seems to exacerbate the problem. std::unordered_set is now slower on both computers. I would expect the sorted keys to bias the performance against std::set, but in this case the real question is more "why is MSVC unordered_set so slow compared to the one from GCC".